# Compare and remove rows based on values [MYSQLi]

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

So this is what I'm trying to do and have no idea how to proceed with.

There are two tables. `db1` and `db2`. Db1 contains two `column`s, `id` and `PriceMin`.

---

`Db2` contains columns `id` and `Price`.

---

`Db1` is the mother database in which each `id` contains a set price. This `db` is static.

---

`Db2` is the child database in which people **vote** for each item ( read: `id` ) and a script uses the `avg()`  function after matching id's and prices to show data.

---

Now, since this is a script which asks for votes, it has a huge flaw: it can be manipulated. So I'm trying to have a script run every couple of hours which goes through `db2`, matches the `id` and deletes each row (vote) from `db2` which has a id and it's price is over 200% of the same `id` in `db1`.

---

My solutions up to now:

1. Have each db be queried and fetched into an array and use `str_replace` via using an `if` function. This does not seem logical nor doable.
2. Use a script before `POST` to check which will double the queries to the DB, and is not logical. It will also be a stupid idea since every vote will require a query.

---

All out of ideas and would really appreciate a guide or advice in which way to go through.

Thanks in advance !

---

EDIT:

Came up with something but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
include ('go.php');
$sql = "delete 
from db2
where db2.id IN (select db1.id where db2.price > db1.price * 2)" or die(mysqli_error($sql));
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
DELETE db2
FROM db2
JOIN db1 ON db2.id = db1.id
WHERE db2.price > db1.price * 2
```

Comment: Worked out perfectly. Thank you so much.